# how to read the first chunk in a large data frame?

Tags: csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a 3GB file and `pd.read_csv(...)` crashes my iPython notebook so instead I have written (in bad style)

```
df = pd.read_csv("train.csv", chunksize=10**6)

for chunk in df:
    print chunk
    break
```

What is more correct?  I just want to see the first million rows.

Comment: What do you mean? You need all 3 lines to see the first million lines. In fact, I would advise you read in smaller pieces because disk IO is generally slower than CPU.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`iterator`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking) parameter to `read_csv`:

```
reader = pd.read_csv("train.csv", iterator=True)
df = reader.get_chunk(10**6)
```

If it's still to big, you can read (and possibly transform or write back to a new file) smaller chunks in a loop until you get what you need.